# Using the clone method without catching CloneNotSupportedException

Tags: java, cloning

I know that when using the clone method you're supposed to catch the CloneNotSupportedException.  However, I recently tried to clone an array of random integers just by invoking .clone( ) on the array, and it worked!  No try-catch block was necessary.  The code was something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class ClonePractice
{
    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
        int[ ] A = new int[100];

        Random random = new Random( );

        for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
            A[i] = 1 + random.nextInt(100); //Get random integer between 1 and 100.

        int[ ] B = A.clone( );

        B[0] = 1000;

        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(A) );

        System.out.println( Arrays.toString(B) );

        // Arrays A and B should have different first values because they are
        // independent objects in memory.

    } // End of main method.

}  // End of ClonePractice class.
```

This code compiles and runs beautifully!  But it does not require catching the CloneNotSupportedException inside a try-catch block.  Could someone please explain why this is the exception to the "rule" about catching that exception.  Thank you!!!

Comment: The compiler knows that arrays are always cloneable, and hence that `clone()` on an array will not raise `CloneNotSupportedException`.

Comment: "when using the clone method you're supposed to catch the CloneNotSupportedException" what gave you that idea?

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for [`Object.clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()) says:

> Note that all arrays are considered to implement the interface Cloneable

Since the compiler knows that arrays are always cloneable, it knows that `clone()` on an array will not raise `CloneNotSupportedException`. It doesn't make that assumption for other `Cloneable` classes, but arrays as usual seem to be dealt with as a special case.

Answer (score 0):

This is by definition. The Java language specification [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7):

> 10.7. Array Members
>  The members of an array type are all of the following:
>   ...
>   The public method clone, which overrides the method of the same name in class Object and throws no checked exceptions.